# Skip nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in CSV. 
One is the URL and other projects.
while reading the Project column, I am getting A, B, nan, nan, nan

how can I run a loop only for A and B and skip all non.

```
names=df.Project.tolist()
for i in names:
   if i.isnull():
     continue
   print(i)
```

Comment: `i.isnan()` try it

Comment: Try `names = df["Project"].dropna()`

Comment: Thanks Chris. This is what I was looking for. i.isnan() is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
names = df["Project"].dropna()
for i in names:
   if i.isnull():
     continue
   print(i)
```

Comment: If you `drop` the `nans`, why do you check :if is null" then? Isn't it redundant?